# SQL Sum across two columns with nulls

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains a time field that is always filled, as well as an override field that is sometimes blank and sometimes a duplicate of the time field.
The override field mirroring time is a policy issue that is out of my control, but has been communicated to stakeholders that this is the field that will be summed first. Both time columns are in the same table.

| id | time | time_override |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id13 | 1.0 |  |
| id14 | 1.2 | 1.0 |
| id15 | 1.0 | 1.0 |

I'm not quite sure how to work this to sum the time_override, unless null, and add the value in time. Appreciate the help with this potentially simple problem

```
SELECT 
SUM(t.time_override) as NUMBER
from rev.TIME as t
```

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` for this: `SELECT SUM(COALESCE(t.time_override, t.time)) as NUMBER FROM rev.Time as t;`

Comment: You could do a union of two queries, then sum from those two queries. q1: select t.time_override where t.time_override IS NOT NULL. q2: select t.time where t.time_override IS NULL. SELECT SUM from the union. I haven't used COALESCE, and JNEvill's solution may be better.

Comment: Just so I also understand what this is doing, coalesce is going to populate the row from t.time_override first, then if it is null, populate it with the t.time value?

Comment: @JeffreyLueken No columns will be populated/saved within the database. `coalesce()` simply looks for the first argument in its list that isn't null and returns that one. So the summation will then add up the override value where available and otherwise fall back to the other value instead.